# WPF Best way of displaying a busy indicator when dynamically creating a page

Tags: wpf, xbap, busyindicator

I have a WPF application that runs as an XBAP in a browser.  On a few pages all the controls are dynamically created depending on what the user selects.  Because of this it can look like the application is not doing anything until all the controls are loaded.  I'd like to have some sort of busy indicator displayed before hand to show the user that the controls are loading, it doesn't have to be animated although would be nice if it did.  I've looked into the telerik busy indicator but this doesn't work as it's really for getting data for a single control and doesn't show until the controls are loaded which defeats the purpose.

I was thinking of displaying an overlay, or something similar, first, containing a loading logo, then load the page behind this and hide the overlay when the controls have loaded.  I was wondering if this was the best way of going about this or if there's a better way?

Comment: There's no better way as all UI operations need to occur in the UI thread. Im worried though, about your statement `On a few pages all the controls are dynamically created depending on what the user selects`. That sounds like you have not applied the proper patterns (MVVM) and are creating all these UI elements in code, which would be bad, and could potentially cause all these performance issues. show some code and maybe we can help you out with that.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to post code but basically a page can contain loads of text boxes, list boxes, drop downs, user controls etc that the user can choose to show or hide on the page depending on what they need so it's highly customisable.  It's the loading of these controls that can take the time.  It is MVVM but I've inherited the code so maybe there is something else that could be done as well.  Cheers anyway will have to look at that and the overlay then.

Comment: @knappster Like what HighCode said, there shouldn't be any need to "load" customised controls. There are a few techniques available to achieve this. You could use DataTriggers to show/hide certain controls based on a property value, you could abstract your sets of controls to UserControls and use a DataTemplate (any DataTemplateSelector) to control which UserControl is used. Anyway I will try to offer an answer for your real problem (mouse hourglass below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I haven't tried this in a XBAP browser app, but it works in WPF Apps without any problems!
I use a DispatcherTimer to show an hourglass when necessary, and abstract this code to a static class.

```
public static class UiServices
{

    /// <summary>
    ///   A value indicating whether the UI is currently busy
    /// </summary>
    private static bool IsBusy;

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the busystate as busy.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetBusyState()
    {
        SetBusyState(true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the busystate to busy or not busy.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="busy">if set to <c>true</c> the application is now busy.</param>
    private static void SetBusyState(bool busy)
    {
        if (busy != IsBusy)
        {
            IsBusy = busy;
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = busy ? Cursors.Wait : null;

            if (IsBusy)
            {
                new DispatcherTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, dispatcherTimer_Tick, Application.Current.Dispatcher);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the Tick event of the dispatcherTimer control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    private static void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dispatcherTimer = sender as DispatcherTimer;
        if (dispatcherTimer != null)
        {
            SetBusyState(false);
            dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    UiServices.SetBusyState();
    // Do your thing
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cheers, I'll give this a go in XBAP browser and see if it works.